# Passing "constant pointers" to functions

Tags: c++

I've written program which performs various operations on a binary tree. At the beginning I set null root pointer, then call a couple of `insert()` functions that add new nodes to the tree.

Finally, I call `search()` function that finds requested structure node and returns it.

---

`insert()` function takes two parameters - reference to the root pointer, and constant int key, which will be converted to the node structure and added to the tree

`search()` function takes "constant root pointer" - not reference, because I want to operate on local pointer directly, and I don't want this to be changed. The other argument it takes is int key.

---

This is the whole program:

```
#include <iostream>

struct node
{
    node *p; // parent
    node *left, *right;
    int key;
};

void insert(node *&root, const int key)
{
    node newElement = {};
    newElement.key = key;

    node *y = NULL;
    while(root)
    {
        if(key == root->key) exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        y = root;
        root = (key < root->key) ? root->left : root->right;
    }

    newElement.p = y;

    if(!y) root = &newElement;
    else if(key < y->key) y->left = &newElement;
    else y->right = &newElement;
}

node* search(const node *root, const int key)
{
    while( (root) && (root->key != key) )
        root = (key < root->key) ? root->left : root->right;

    return root;
}

int main()
{
    using namespace std;
    node *root = NULL;
    insert(root, 5);
    insert(root, 2);

    cout << search(root, 5)->key << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

**My question is -** Why doesn't search function work? It displays an error - return value type does not match the function type. But I return the poiner, just like it says in the declaration!

Also, is `"const"` keyword here o.k.?

Comment: Well, `root` is `const node*`, and your return value is `node*`. It should be changed to `const node*`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`root` is `const node*`, and your return value is `node*`. It should be changed to `const node*`.

```
const node* search(const node *root, const int key);
```

If you need a `search` function to give you back a non-const `node`, then it needs to take a non-const `node` parameter. You can provide an overload to allow for both possibilities

```
node* search(node *root, const int key);
```

Comment: I think OP needs to be able to modify the found item, so two overloads is probably a good idea, one const and one non-const.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are returning the same pointer you cannot have a const argument and a non-const return. Instead write two versions, one const and one non-const.

This is one of the few cases where const_cast is justified. Write two versions of your search function, one can call the other using const_cast.

```
const node* search(const node *root, const int key)
{
    while( (root) && (root->key != key) )
        root = (key < root->key) ? root->left : root->right;

    return root;
}

node* search(node *root, const int key)
{
    return const_cast<node *>(search(const_cast<const node *>(root), key));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside `search`, the variable `root` is a `const node*`. However, you're trying to return it as a `node*`. You can't do this because it would violate const-correctness.  If you returned a pointer to a genuinely `const` object, the client would be able to then modify that object.

Instead, you'll need to make the function return a `const node*`. Either that, or `root` should just be a `node*`.